# How to hook up click on Notification group?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to override or create listener for click on Notification Group? I can't find any information or documentation about this. I know how to set PendingIntent to single notification but not for group. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to a specific behavior when the user clicks the notification group you can create a [group summary](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group#set_a_group_summary) and add a `PendingIntent` to it.